# Looking for a protocol, any hints?

Tags: hardware

I am looking for a multi-purpose wire protocol for Arduino.

Requirements:

1. Range of at least 500ft (200m)
2. No shield required
3. Able to communicate between Arduino and Raspberry Pi
4. Be able to run "point-to-multipoint"

Comment: Are you looking for hardware or software recommendations?

Comment: To quote my tag: "Hardware".

Comment: What do you mean by "No shield required"? Do you mean no extra electronics on the Arduino?

Comment: Yeah, no extra electronics.

Comment: So you want hardware, but you don't want electronics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing that will work given those constraints.

You only have low power 5V signals on the Arduino which won't handle your distance requirements.

You could look into [RS-485](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) using a [shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11959) on the arduino side and a [breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10124) on the Raspberry Pi.